# How to get the SOAP Envelope format

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET, when we brows an asmx web service in the browser, we can click on any of the exposed services and see the SOAP format of the xml to send to the return format of the return value.

Now, in the runtime, I can connect to asmx web service, and get all exposed methods.

How dynamically I can get the format of the SOAP message to send, and the return xml format?

Comment: Typically you instead [work with service references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019)

Comment: But I'm doing that in the run time.

Comment: I don't understand. You usually don't care about the soap message format because you work at a higher abstraction  with the service client.

Comment: But I'm developing an application using VB.NET, when a user types the URL of soap service, I need to tell him that the request format should be like This, and the return format will be like this.

Comment: There is already a facility for that by browsing to the web service. Can't you just give them the URL?

Comment: Is there a way using code to do that?

Comment: Yes, when you browse to it you are simply doing a HTTP GET request. [You can obtain the response body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) and parse/display however you want but there is a reason that wsdl files are often publicly exposed - it is so you don't have to do any work.

Comment: There is now other way to capture the request format without parsing, same as ASP.NET do when click on the service?

Comment: Yes, you can re-implement what visual studio (not asp.net) does when you add a service reference which is the [svcutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) utility.